# Elements in Grid should change spanning dependend on attribute; does not work in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css-grid

I want create some kind of tiled interface.
The tiles are `li` elements in a normal css grid, placed in one column, each tile contains a `details` element.
If the details element is expanded, this tile should span two columns.

This [Minimum example][1] works on Chrome, but not really in Firefox.
The view changes only after some events i don't know (Toggling the Developers Windows for example)
Yes, i enabled the `:has` selector in firefox, this is not the problem.
(Tested in both Normal and Developer Preview versions of the browsers.)

Any recommendations how to get this working in Firefox?

[1]:

```css
.gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.tile > details {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-block-end: 20px;
  min-height: 40px;
  /*height: auto;*/
  /*max-height: 100px;*/
  background: oklch(84.71% 0.123 93.18);
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.tile > details[open] {
  /*max-height: 600px;*/
}

.tile > details > summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.tile > details > summary > * {
  display: inline;
}

.tile:has(details[open]) {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
<ul role="list" class="gridcontainer">
    <li class="tile">
        <details id="tile1">
            <summary class="summary1">
                <h3>Title<small> – Subtitle</small></h3>
            </summary>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        </div>
        <div>
            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </details>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">
        <details id="tile2">
            <summary class="summary1">
                <h3>Title<small> – Subtitle</small></h3>
            </summary>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        </div>
        <div>
            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </details>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">
        <details id="tile3" >
            <summary class="summary1">
                <h3>Title<small> – Subtitle</small></h3>
            </summary>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        </div>
        <div>
            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </details>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">
        <details id="tile4" >
            <summary class="summary1">
                <h3>Title<small> – Subtitle</small></h3>
            </summary>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        </div>
        <div>
            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </details>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">
        <details id="tile5" >
            <summary class="summary1">
                <h3>Title<small> – Subtitle</small></h3>
            </summary>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        </div>
        <div>
            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </details>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">
        <details id="tile6" >
            <summary class="summary1">
                <h3>Title<small> – Subtitle</small></h3>
            </summary>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        </div>
        <div>
            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </details>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">
        <details id="tile7" >
            <summary class="summary1">
                <h3>Title<small> – Subtitle</small></h3>
            </summary>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        </div>
        <div>
            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </details>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">
        <details id="tile8" >
            <summary class="summary1">
                <h3>Title<small> – Subtitle</small></h3>
            </summary>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        </div>
        <div>
            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </details>
    </li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Comment: what about .tile:focus-within {   grid-column-end: span 2; } ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Comment: @Snuffy The tile is reduced to one column only after i click another tile, apart from that, i would use this as a workaround.

Comment: So it's said explicitly, `:has` is not yet supported in Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has . Ideally you would set `.open` on the `li.tile`, rather than on `details`.

Comment: Please add your code ("Minimum example") to the question.

Comment: @scrhartley :has selector is partially working in firefox https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/when-is-has-css-selector-going-to-be-fully-implemented-in/idi-p/23794

Comment: @TobiasWohlfarth I know, but I didn't want to complicate the matter and "partially working hidden behind a flag" is as good as not working for our purposes. "It can be forced to work" and fully supported are two different things really.

Comment: May be get rid of the "tile" and make details direct descendant of gridcontainer?